avd is open in taskbar but not displayed
The AVD is open but it doesn't display when I click on it.
avd in taskbar
i use android studio 2024.2.1 ladybug
I was able to find a file that seems to better describe the problem.
When I edit this file and change the scale to a positive number, the problem is temporarily solved, but if I open and close the emulator again, the problem is back.
File path : myavdname\emulator-user.ini
window.x = 100
window.y = 100
window.scale = -1.000000
resizable.config.id = -1
posture = 0
uuid = 1732467260850



How can I fix this problem so that every time I open the emulator the scale is at its correct number and does not change? I emphasize that this problem occurred after the Android Studio update.
